# Qt msvc2015 and windows kit 10 for windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I am trying to port a Qt project that I have developed on Linux first. It is the first time that I'm experiencing building on Windows, and the fact that I could not solved the problem might come from a very obvious missing thing.

The Windows configurations I tried until now are the next one:

- Windows 10 with Qt 5.8 MSVC 2015, Windows Kit 10, Qt Creator 4.5
- Windows 7 SP1 with Qt 5.8 MSVC 2015, Windows Kit 10, Qt Creator 4.6

With both configs, I obtain an executable file that can be successfully run on the host machine, but when I deploy the application on freshly installed Windows 10, the application starts for few seconds and then stops(/crashes?). However, neither error messages, nor recoveries dialog, nor event log are showing up anything.

On freshly installed Windows 7 SP1, I get an error message saying that the entry point for CreateFile2 couldn't be find. I know that this function has been added since Windows 8, but I cannot understand why the application is built with such a entry point although I define the _WIN32_WINNT as follow in my .pro file:

```
DEFINES += "_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601"
```

I tried to the WINVER definition as well, without success:

```
DEFINES += "WINVER=0x0601"
```

I assumed no DLL were missing using a dependency software available at [this git](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies). I also tried the "more than depreciated" Dependency Walker, which didn't show missing libs.

By advance, thank you to the Windowsians who will save me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I found the problem! 
The problem was coming from this external library I was building aside, and then linking to my final app in static mode. After rebuilding the external lib with the correct _WIN32_WINNT, it worked!
Hope this topic will help winnoob like me :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured out that one of the static libraries my project is using, and that I compiled through VS 2017 was containing the CreateFile2 reference (using dumpbin.exe). I recompiled it using the right _WIN32_WINNT value, and also fresh-recompiled the Qt project. However, the CreateFile2 reference is still present.